# R 'All' function not working within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to mark every row in my dataset when that row AND ALL the following 5 rows are above a certain value (2 standard deviations above the mean). This is the code I'm using:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(linnaeus)){
    if (all((linnaeus$delta[row:row+5]) > ((linnaeus$mean_delta[row]) +((linnaeus$sd_delta[row])*2)))
    ){
(linnaeus$start[row] <- 1)
}}
```

[image]

However, as you can see in the picture. It will now mark a row (blue) when the row that's 5 rows down is high enough (red). If I print the code specifically for these rows, the output is FALSE. Yet in this for loop it does not seem to work. For clarity, I only want a row to be marked, when it and ALL the following 5 rows are higher than 2 SDs above the mean.

Comment: `row:row+5` is equivalent to `row+5`. For example, see `1:1+5`. I think you need `row:(row+5)`.

Comment: This will still fail, though, but in a different way. When you get to within 4 rows of the bottom, then `row:(row+5)` will exceed the index length. You likely want a window function, perhaps `zoo::rollapply(seq_len(nrow(linnaeus)), 6, function(z) all(linnaeus$delta[z] > linnaeus$mean_delta[z[1]] + 2*linnaeus$sd_delta[z[1]]), align="left", partial=TRUE)`.